# Reading XML for iTunes RSS feed

Tags: xml, vb.net, xml-parsing, rss, xmlnode

Hey all i am reading my XML RSS feed like so:

```
Dim rssSubNode As XmlNode = rssNode.SelectSingleNode("title")
Dim title As String = If(rssSubNode IsNot Nothing, rssSubNode.InnerText, "")

rssSubNode = rssNode.SelectSingleNode("itunes:author")
Dim author As String = If(rssSubNode IsNot Nothing, rssSubNode.InnerText, "")
```

The **title** is retrieved just fine. However, when it try's to get the author it has an error of:

```
Value of type 'System.Xml.XmlNodeList' cannot be converted to 'System.Xml.XmlNode'.
```

My XML file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss xmlns:itunes="http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd" version="2.0">
  <channel>
      <item>
         <title>First Chaper</title>
         <itunes:author>My Name Here</itunes:author>
         <itunes:subtitle>First Chapter: The blah blah.</itunes:subtitle>
         etc etc....
```

What do i need to add in order to grab that value?

Comment: The `itunes` part is the a namespace prefix (see the `xmlns:itunes="..."`), so I think you have to add a XmlNamespaceManager in order for the select to be able to parse and resolve the namespace prefix. See [`XmlNode.SelectSingleNode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/h0hw012b.aspx). I didn't write this as an answer as I don't use vb.net, so cannot really provide any useful code - but I have encountered XML namespace issues before :-)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that SelectSingleNode takes XPath and not just a node name. So when you put a something with a colon there, it assumes that you are talking about a namespace, which was not provided to it, and so it throws that exception.

The simple answer then is to change your code to be:

```vb
rssSubNode = rssNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[name()='itunes:author']")
```

This effectively allows you to ignore the special characters. If you want to properly use namespaces, then I suggest you look into the [XmlNamespaceManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ske01k15.aspx).